# How to extract links anywhere at any depth?

Tags: scrapy

I am scraping dell.com website, my goal is pages like http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&cs=19&l=en&s=dhs&sku=A7098144. How do I set link extracting rules so they find these pages anywhere at any depth? As I know, by default there is no limit on depth. If I do:

```
rules = (
    Rule (
        SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r"productdetail\.aspx"),
        callback="parse_item"
    ),
)
```

it doesn't work: it crawles only the starting page. If I do:

```
rules = (
    Rule (
        SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r".*")
    ),
    Rule (
        SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r"productdetail\.aspx"),
        callback="parse_item"
    ),
)
```

it crawles product pages but doesn't scrape them (I mean doesn't call parse_item() on them). I tried include follow=True on the first rule although if there is no callback it should be True by default.

EDIT:

This is the rest of my code except for parse function:

```
import re
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.http import Request

class DellSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'dell.com'
    start_urls = ['http://www.dell.com/sitemap']
    rules = (
        Rule (
            SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r".*")
        ),
        Rule (
            SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r"productdetail\.aspx"),
            callback="parse_item"
        ),
    )
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of your spider's initialization? Everything but the parse and other functions.

Answer (score 1):

From the [CrawlSpider documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider):

> If multiple rules match the same link, the first one will be used, according to the order they’re defined in this attribute.

Thus, you need to invert the order of your `Rule`s. Currently `.*` will match everything, before `productdetail\.aspx` is checked at all.

This should work:

```
rules = (
    Rule (
        SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r"productdetail\.aspx"),
        callback="parse_item"
    ),
    Rule (
        SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r".*")
    ),
)
```

However, you will have to make sure that links will be followed in `parse_item`, if you want to follow links on *productdetail* pages. The second rule will not be called on *productdetail* pages.

Comment: Yes, I tried this too. But in this case it scrapes very few product pages (about 10) and then continues to crawl other pages (I checked and these other pages contain links to product pages but they are ignored). I can't understand what is happening here.

Comment: Maybe it helps adding debug `print` like "Crawling URL X", "Found URL Y on URL X" etc. and letting the crawler run with `DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 2` or so in `settings.py`. Then you would see which URLs are found and which ignored.

Comment: Yes, I did that, didn't help. As I said earlier, spider behaves weird.